# How to make String.Format work in conjunction with Resource File values from Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a resource file in Asp.net and I am reading the value from there as follows

```
var val1 = '<% = Resources.Test.FirstValue%>';  //Hello
var val2 = '<% = Resources.Test.SecondValue%>';  //World          
alert(val1);
alert(val2);
```

It does work properly. But Suppose I want to use the String.Format function in C# inorder to make it as "Hello - World" as under

```
var val3 = '<%= string.Format("{0} - {1}",<% = Resources.Test.FirstValue%>,<% = Resources.Test.SecondValue%> %>';
```

It is throwing some compile time error

```
Invalid expression term '<'
Invalid expression term '='
) expected
; expected
Invalid expression term ')'
```

Cannot I use a server side function like that way in Javascript . However, the below works

```
var val3 = '<%= string.Format("{0} - {1}","Hello","World") %>';
```

Well I know that the problem can be solve using javascript itself. I am just curious to see how to get the String.Format function of C# work in Javascript in conjunction with Resource file values.

So, please give the correction /solution pertaining to String.Format and Resource file values only.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need 1 set of `<%=` and `%>` for this. You're also missing the closing `)` for `string.Format`.

```
var val3 = '<%= string.Format("{0} - {1}", Resources.Test.FirstValue, Resources.Test.SecondValue) %>';
```

But, everything between a set of `<%=` and `%>` is C#, which doesn't support further use of these template operators. You only need these operators again after you've ended the previous set:

```
var val3 = '<%= Resources.Test.FirstValue %> - <%= Resources.Test.SecondValue %>';
```